# Creating a latitude longitude image

Tags: geography, geodesy

The `GeoPosition` of Eureka, California is:

```
GeoPosition[{40.7933, -124.155}]
```

Has anyone ever created an image of the world with latitude and longitude lines? What would be a good way using *Mathematica* to create an image showing that these `GeoPosition` numbers make sense for the city of Eureka, California?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/ConstructAGlobeShowingAllWeatherStations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following shows an equirectangular projection with geographic gridlines positioned every 10 degrees of latitude and longitude, and starting at the geographic zero reference points for the northern hemisphere.

A marker is also placed at the location of Eureka using your coordinates. One can then approximate the position of the marker by using the gridlines and convince oneself that those coordinates are reasonable for the position of Eureka, CA.

```
GeoGraphics[
  GeoMarker@GeoPosition[{40.7933, -124.155}],
  GeoGridLines -> {5, 13}, 
  GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Opacity[0.5]],
  GeoRange -> {{0, 60}, {-130, 0}}, GeoRangePadding -> None,
  GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular",
  ImageSize -> Full,
  Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[15, Black, Bold],
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 18, FontWeight -> Plain] & /@ {"Longitude", "Latitude"})
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Eureka", "California", "UnitedStates"}]]` could have been used to get the required position.

Comment: @MarcoB Fabulous answer. It introduces me to so much at a beginner's level. I also added Frame->True which will be helpful when I explain this to my colleagues. Thanks so much.

Comment: @David you're very welcome. adding a `Frame` does make a lot of sense as well.